# Count Points in R scatter plot above/below threshold

Tags: r, plot

I have a scatter plot of two samples of rna seq data normalized to a log2 scale. I am working in R. I expect most values to fall on the x=y line, however I am interested in finding the amount of points that fall outside that range to eliminate the 'noise'. How do I get the count of points above and below a certain threshold (i.e. the red lines: 1+logx, 1+logy).

```
plot(log2(data$SRR850589_sorted/19108931*1000000+.5),
             log2(data$SRR850604_sorted/22989410*1000000+.5),
             xlab="log(SRR850589)", ylab="lg(SRR85604)")
abline(0,1,col='cyan')
abline(1,1,col='red')
abline(-1,1,col='red')
```

[image]

Comment: We do not have your data so we cannot run your code to see the red lines.

Comment: Sorry this is my first post on here. But I don't think the data is essential. Based off of the graph I have I want to obtain the # of points above the upper bound red line and points below lower bound red line. My x axis is composed of the normalized values of SRR850589_sorted and my y axis is composed of the normalized values of SRR850604_sorted. Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

For each x,y pair, use the fitted function to determine how far each y-value is from the fitted line at each x-value. For example, let's assume we want to mark points that are at least 5 units away from the fitted line (in the vertical direction):

```
set.seed(10)
x = runif(100, 0, 10)
y = 2*x + 5 + rnorm(100,0,5)
m1 = lm(y ~ x)
```

To get the count of points more than 5 units away:

```
table(abs(y - (coef(m1)[1] + coef(m1)[2]*x)) > 5)
```

> ```
> FALSE  TRUE 
>    63    37
> ```

To plot the points:

```
plot(x,y,type="n")
abline(coef(m1))
abline(coef(m1) + c(5,0), col="red")
abline(coef(m1) - c(5,0), col="red")
points(x,y, pch=16, col=ifelse(abs(y - (coef(m1)[1] + coef(m1)[2]*x)) > 5, "blue","red"))
```

[image]

Comment: I can already see OP’s next question: how do you obtain the fitted function? ;-)